# Jetpack Compose lazycolumn performance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to jetpack compose and learning it from code of [`JetpackCompose` Basics](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-basics#0)
so I have found in the [create a performant lazy list](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-basics#8)

> Note: LazyColumn doesn't recycle its children like `RecyclerView`. It
> emits new `Composables` as you scroll through it and is still
> performant, as emitting `Composables` is relatively cheap compared to
> instantiating Android Views.

so how emitting new composable is cheap and performant, and then why not to just using column and compose the whole list for one time instead of keep emitting composable items while scrolling even if the emitting `composables` is only the items visible by layout

Update : if the visible items is 10, so before user scroll the items from 0 to 9 is visible and has been rendered, now the user has scrolled up and the visible items from 5 to 14, is jetpack compose removed the 5 items that have been previously rendered and if user scroll down, they will be recomposed or  jetpack compose keep all rendered views in memory no matter if it visible or not

Answer (score 1):

Because there's a limit to the definition of "cheap", but no limit to how big a list can be.  It may be cheap to output 100-200 composables (which I'm not convinced of, but lets say so for the sake of argument).  It isn't cheap to output 10K of them.  Which a list of results backed by a DB could easily be.

So you still don't want to output everything all time time.  But it may be relatively cheap to output everything a user would reasonably scroll to, because nobody goes to the end of a 10K list.  Thus making it a reasonable compromise based on common user behavior.  You'd lose performance as they scroll further down the page, but the percentage of users who do that is small enough you may not care.

Comment: ok, I got it, can you please reread the question, I have made an update

Comment: I think you haven`t explained the important part of the questions `how emitting new composable is cheap and performant` by answering that the root cause is discovered hence the lack of understanding is covered.

Answer (score 0):

1. In lazy column, only the composables for the visible items are rendered and stay in memory.
2. The Composables for off-screen items are not kept in memory and are recycled as the user scrolls through the list.
3. When the user scrolls and the visible items change, the LazyColumn emits new Composables for the new visible items and recycles the Composables for the off-screen items.
4. The Composables for the still visible items are not removed from
   memory and will not be recomposed unless they need to be updated.

in your example, when the user scrolls and the visible items change from 0 to 9 to 5 to 14, the Composables for the off-screen items (0 to 4) are recycled and the Composables for the new visible items (10 to 14) are emitted. The Composables for the still visible items (5 to 9) are not removed from memory and will not be recomposed.
If the data they are displaying change, of course they need to be recomposed btw.

so, why do they call it a cheap lazy column? there is no exact definition of cheap. Compared to a standard column, it does not attempt to create all items at the same time.